# Can I add a search box to a Django Admin Add page?

Tags: django, django-admin

In a Django 3.0 app, I have a Donor Model with a foreign key to the donor's congressional district:

```
# models.py
class Donor(models.Model):
    """A class to represent an individual donor"""
    
    name = models.CharField(
        help_text = "Donor's name"
    )
    district = models.ForeignKey(
        District,
        help_text = "Donor's congressional district"
    )

class District(models.Model):
    """A class to represent a U.S. congressional district"""
    
    dist_name = models.CharField(
        help_text = "District name"
    )
```

In the Admin Add page for Donor, there's a drop-down selection menu for District.  The problem is that there are 435 congressional districts in the U.S.  That's an awful lot to scroll through each time I add a Donor, so I'd like to add a search box.

Django has the ability to define [search fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields).  I tried to do so:

```
# admin.py

@admin.register(Donor)
class DonorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['district']
```

This did not affect the Donor Add page.  'District' still shows up as an enormous drop-down, and there are no search features anywhere on the page.

The `search_fields` documentation says specifically

> Set search_fields to enable a search box on the admin **change list** page.

Emphasis mine: `search_fields` seems to apply to only the Change List page, not the Add page.  I assume this is why my attempt didn't work.

Is it possible to add a search box to a Django Admin Add page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a search box to Django admin pages.

Add this to your admin class:

search_fields = ['name', 'author',.......] #add the fields you want to search

And the search box it will appear

Answer (score 0):

No you can't add a search box to django admin pages.

Comment: Thanks for a direct response.  Can you point me toward any documentation or other information that would let me verify this?

Comment: I will when I get or see one.